# Override "International phone" field placeholder

Tags: 8

I've installed phone_international contrib module for Drupal 8 project and want to override placeholder.
In widget setting there are no placeholder.
Also tried to change it with form_alter_hook and hook_field_widget_form_alter, but without result.

```
// In form_alter_hook
$form['account']['field_account_contact_phone']['widget'][0]['placeholder'] = 'Custom placeholder';
```

Where "field_account_contact_phone" is "International phone" field.
After that code I see the following error:

```
"placeholder" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Element.php).
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  Since you talk about custom code please add it to your question. Thank you

Comment: You have to add placeholder to key #attributes like this: `$form['account']['field_account_contact_phone']['widget'][0]['#attributes']['placeholder'] = 'Custom placeholder';`

Comment: How can I see placeholder is added by JS.